# Install duplicate copies of an application concurrently

Tags: windows-xp, sandbox

I've got a database application which seems to write some configuration to the registry.  I'm wondering if there is a way to "sandbox" or "virtualize" (short of running a full VM) such that I can install two copies of the application concurrently with different configuration?

I will petition the vendor if necessary, but they may charge for "custom" work.  The database will run in Server 2008r2, though testing is in an XP VM presently.

Comment: If the application write to the registry for some or all of its configuration settings then without vendor support what you want won't be possible.  An easier solution would be to write a script file to change the configuration between one install and another.

Comment: @Ramhound I was afraid that might be the case.  I'm currently investigating a product called Sandboxie, but I'm not too hopeful.